# Advent Calender - Enable button when the date has reached

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm currently working on a little advent calender application.
The WinForm contains 24 buttons, which are disabled by default.

Now I need to reconsider this part of the code.

```
        do
        {
            switch (_currentDate.ToShortDateString()) // uses NIST time server
            {
                case "01.12.2014":
                {
                    btn1.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                }

                case "02.12.2014":
                {
                    btn2.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                }

                case "03.12.2014":
                {
                    btn3.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                }

                    //committed

                case "24.12.2014":
                {
                    btn24.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            _currentDate = _currentDate.AddDays(-1);
        } while (_currentDate.ToShortDateString() != new DateTime(2014, 11, 30).ToShortDateString());
```

Is there a cool way to shorten that piece of code?
Because this code snippet looks a bit to redundant to me.

Comment: FYI, this line: `_currentDate.AddDays(-1);` ...doesn't actually do anything!

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely right. Edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

- Use a button array instead of drawing each button manually. Work through this example: [Easy Code to create Button Array](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131696/Easy-Code-to-Create-Button-Array)
- Take a look at this: [Description of the DateTime structure in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Use **Month** and **Year** properties to ensure the correct month and year (12, 2014)
- Now use the **Day** property to build your code as follows:

suppose your button array is called CalenderButtons and the respective indices are 0 for the 1st of December, 1 for the 2nd, etc.

If you want to enable just 1 button, use:

```
CalenderButtons[_currentDate.Day-1].Enabled = true;
```

If you want to enable all buttons beginning from the 1st up to the current day:

```
for (int i=0; i<_currentDate.Day; i++) 
{
   CalenderButtons[i].Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve it, by using the Button Array sample with some custom tweaks I've needed. Now the button part is approx. 20-25 lines only.